# How can I Transfer mysql wkt directly into a postgis table?

Tags: postgis, mysql, well-known-text

I have wkt geometry data in mysql stored in blob format.
I need to get this data into a postgis db and am looking for the quickest-easiest way to do it. I have managed to select the data "ASTEXT" but can then only copy it into QGIS -> export to shape -> import to postgis....but this is probably not the easiest way.

Is there a way to directly import a table from mysql into postgis?

thanks for any help,

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this with mysql but I think [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) should be able to do it for you.